# Problem with NaN values and fillna function python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fillna

I got an issue, hopefully someone has a great solution.

I am reading an Excel file. And I use keep_default_na=False because there is a productname called "NA" and I dont want pandas changing it to NaN.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Import_orders.xlsx', keep_default_na=False)
```

But the problem is when i run below code, it does nothing. Because there are no NaN values to fill. Because i used "keep_default_na=False". Is there a way to fill the empty fields. Thanks in advance!

```
df['Action for Contact'] = df['Action for Contact'].fillna('Update')
```

Comment: If you are passing `keep_default_na=False`, then you need to explicitly pass the subset of values to treat as `NaN`.

Comment: Do you know how i can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the values considered as nan, just exclude NA, like so:

```
na_values = ['',
             '#N/A',
             '#N/A N/A',
             '#NA',
             '-1.#IND',
             '-1.#QNAN',
             '-NaN',
             '-nan',
             '1.#IND',
             '1.#QNAN',
             '<NA>',
             'N/A',
             'NA',
             'NULL',
             'NaN',
             'n/a',
             'nan',
             'null']

na_values.remove('NA')

pd.read_excel(file_path, keep_default_na=False, na_values=na_values)
```